# how to deselect cells when all cells are select in `dhtmlxgrid`?

Tags: dhtmlx

When you select all cells in a `Dhtmlxgrid`. There is no place to click on grid to deselect cells. Please look at this example. 
http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/02_clipboard/01_grid_selection.html

Answer (score 0):

I think by 'select cell' here you are meant 'In Store' checkbox column. You will need to attach #master_checkbox in header in order to have a header level checkbox to select/unselect all checkboxes for that column. Something like below:

```
myGrid.attachHeader("1,2,3,#master_checkbox,5");
```